# Jsoup get different HTML,only default query page, not result page

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm trying to retrieve some parking data from website to show in Android.
Now I'm trying to query some data (AB-5678) from this site
[E-BILL](https://ebill.ba.org.tw/CPP//DesktopDefault.aspx?TabIndex=4&TabId=153) (Chinese page).
Both query page and result page use the same URL.

### Chrome console

The following are what I post in Chrome console after a successful query.

(Header)
[image]

(Data)
[image]

I tried to query again with Chrome plugin - POSTMAN , who also gave me a successful result page.
[image]

However, when I leverage Jsoup to query data as following

```
    Connection.Response resource = Jsoup.connect("https://ebill.ba.org.tw/CPP//DesktopDefault.aspx?TabIndex=4&TabId=153")
        .timeout(Define.WEBTIMEOUT)
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://ebill.ba.org.tw/CPP//DesktopDefault.aspx?TabIndex=4&TabId=153")
        .data("__EVENTTARGET", "")
        .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
        .data("__VIEWSTATE", resource.parse().getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").val())
        .data("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", resource.parse().getElementById("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR").val())
        .data("ctl00$Desktopthreepanes1$ThreePanes$ctl13$VehicleType", "C")
        .data("ctl00$Desktopthreepanes1$ThreePanes$ctl13$CarNo", "AB-5678")
                .data("ctl00$Desktopthreepanes1$ThreePanes$ctl13$OkButton", "")
        .referrer("https://ebill.ba.org.tw/CPP//DesktopDefault.aspx?TabIndex=4&TabId=153")
        .header("Cache-Control","no-cache")
        .header("Host", "ebill.ba.org.tw")
        .header("Origin", "https://ebill.ba.org.tw")
        .header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .cookie("IsPassClientEnvironDetection", "true")
        .cookie("IsPassMobileClientEnvironDetection","true")
        .cookie("c","1450682673891")
        .followRedirects(true)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36")
        .cookies(resource.cookies())
        .timeout(Define.WEBTIMEOUT)
        .post();
```

However I get is nothing but the default query page.
I googled every possible answer, and I don't think this result from the cookies of JavaScript, and I have set the userAgent.....Do I miss anything?

Comment: Why do you send the cookies twice?

Comment: No, the resource.cookies() only contains {ASP.NET_SessionId}, so I have to send the other 3 keys to pass the JS check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong.

I tried to analysis the content-length of each post, and the value is ~1100 in Chrome but only ~500 in my jsoup.

After tracing, I found the _VIEWSTATE val length should be 700+ but always 200 in jsoup...

Finally, i found that the cookies should be set in [GET] stage, or this website will give you a wrong __VIEWSTATE value.

that is,

```
    Connection.Response resource = Jsoup.connect("https://ebill.ba.org.tw/CPP//DesktopDefault.aspx?TabIndex=4&TabId=153")
        .timeout(Define.WEBTIMEOUT)
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();
```

should be...

```
    Connection.Response resource = Jsoup.connect("https://ebill.ba.org.tw/CPP//DesktopDefault.aspx?TabIndex=4&TabId=153")
        .cookie("IsPassClientEnvironDetection", "true")
        .cookie("IsPassMobileClientEnvironDetection", "true")
        .timeout(Define.WEBTIMEOUT)
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();
```